# Passing Static and Dynamic attribute to htmlAttribute in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the scenario where i will be adding two attribute.

One is dynamic i.e ***readonly*** based on user role & another is static i.e ***id***

I tried this below but it is not working for me.

> The attribute rendered in HTML for below is
>
> **readonlystr = , id = 'emp-name'**

```
var readonlystr = (Model.Role.EmpEdit) ? "" : "readonly=readonly";

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { readonlystr, @id = "emp-name" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { readonlystr, @id = "emp-age" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { readonlystr, @id = "emp-city" })
```

Any suggestion to achieve this by combining two attributes and pass it?

Answer (score 1):

```
var readonlystr = Model.Role.EmpEdit ? new Dictionary<string, object>() : new Dictionary<string, object> { { "readonly", "readonly" } };

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, readonlystr.Union(new Dictionary<string, object>{{"id", "emp-name"}}).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @{
        Dictionary<string, object> attribs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (!Model.Role.EmpEdit) {
            attribs.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        }
        attribs.Add("id", "");
    }

    @{attribs["id"] = "emp-name";}
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, attribs)
    @{attribs["id"] = "emp-age";}
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, attribs)
```